# How to display dialog upon launching Android app

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How do you display a dialog box upon launching android application.

Here is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder swipeAlert;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    swipeAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    swipeAlert.setMessage("Swipe to see map");
    swipeAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
```

But when I launch my android app, nothing displays. How come?

Comment: Anytime you launch it or just the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add

`swipeAlert.show();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `show` method to display it.

Add this at last

```
swipeAlert.show();
```